# Number of comma-separated fields in a text file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm trying to build an awk statement to read this file:

```
A   1,2,3   *
A   4,5,6   **
B   1
B   4,5     *
```

and build a file like this:

```
A   1,2,3   *    3   1   0.333
A   4,5,6   **   3   2   0.666
B   1            1   0   0
B   4,5     *    2   1   0.5
```

In this new file, the first three columns are the same as in the original file. The fourth column must contain the number of comma-separated elements in column 2. The fifth column must contain the number of characters in column 3. The last column contains the proportion of column 5 on column 4 (i.e., column 5 divided by column 4).

I'm trying the following code:

```
awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"(NF","$2 -1)"\t"length($3)"\t"(length($3)/(NF","$2-1))}' file1 > file2
```

But I got the following output:

```
A   1,2,3   *    3,0   1   0.333333
A   4,5,6   **   3,3   2   0.666667
B   1            2,0   0   0
B   4,5     *    3,3   1   0.333333
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong for column 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be hoping that `(NF","$2 -1)` will be treated as a function that will return the number of comma-delimited elements in field `$2` - it won't. `NF` is always the number of fields in the *record*.

Instead, you can use awk's `split` function `split($2,a,",")` which splits field `$2` into an array `a` and returns the number of elements. *You can also tidy up the code by using setting the output filed separator to tab instead of using explicit "\t" in your print statement*

```
awk '{l2=split($2,a,","); OFS="\t"; print $1, $2, $3, l2, length($3), length($3)/l2}' file1
```

Comment: I pasted your code, and I get back `awk: line 1: illegal reference to array a` . So I tried: `awk '{split($2,a,",")}' file1; awk '{OFS="\t"; print $1, $2, $3, length(a), length($3), length($3)/length(a)}' file1 > file2` which does not give errors, but column 4 has zeros.

Comment: OK apparently `mawk` doesn't support `length()` on an array variable - please see updated answer

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Perl approach:

```
$ perl -lane '@k=($F[1]=~/,/g); $i=$#k+2; $l=length($F[2]); 
              print "@F $i $l ", $l/$i' file 
A 1,2,3 * 3 1 0.333333333333333
A 4,5,6 ** 3 2 0.666666666666667
B 1 1  0
B 4,5 * 2 1 0.5
```

Or, with `printf` for pretty formatting:

```
$ perl -lane '@k=($F[1]=~/,/g); $i=$#k+2; $l=length($F[2]); 
              printf "%s %-5s %-3s %s %3s %10f\n",@F,$i,$l,$l/$i' file 
A 1,2,3 *   3   1   0.333333
A 4,5,6 **  3   2   0.666667
B 1     1      0   0.000000
B 4,5   *   2   1   0.500000
```

#### Explanation

- `-lane` : the `-l` removes trailing newlines from each input line; the `-a` automatically splits each input line into the array `@F` on whitespace; the `-n` means "read the input file line by line" and the `-e` lets you pass a script as a commandline parameter.
- `@k=($F[1]=~/,/g); $i=$#k+2;` : the array `@k` contains all the commas found in the second field. Then, `$i` is set to the greatest index is `@F` (`$#F`) plus two. The plus 2 is needed because i) arrays are counted from 0 so the greatest index of a single-element array will be 0. We're counting commas, not values, so we need to add one more since `1,2` has two values but only one comma.
- `$l=length($F[2]);` : `$l` is now the number of characters of the 3d field.
- `print "@F $i $l ", $l/$i` : print the requested information. `@F` is the line from the input file, and the rest are what you asked for.